# reselect CreateStructuredSelector difference in properties

Tags: reselect, react-boilerplate

Maybe this is not necessarily a reselect question

```
const makeSelectError = () => createSelector(
  selectGlobal,
  (globalState) => globalState.get('error')
);
```

and in reselect we use

```
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  error: makeSelectError(),
});
```

why can't we use like below?

```
const makeSelectError = createSelector(
      selectGlobal,
      (globalState) => globalState.get('error')
    );
```

and use like below in reselect

```
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  error: makeSelectError,
});
```

Are there any issues/disadvantages with my code, or is that a standard practice?

Answer (score 4):

Not only is the second way valid and correct it has other advantages.

With the first snippet you provide:

```
const makeSelectError = () => createSelector(
  selectGlobal,
  (globalState) => globalState.get('error')
);
```

`makeSelectError` is a factory function in that every time it is called it is returning a new and unique selector.

This means that every time a simple `mapStateToProps` function is called a new selector will be made and the result of the selector will be computed again.
This means that you will be losing the key benefit of `reselect` that is memoization.

So for simple cases you could just do the following:

```
const getSomePieceOfState = state => state.someArea.someDetail;
const getAnotherPieceOfState = state => state.anotherArea.anotherItem;

const getSomeCombinedState = createSelector(
  getSomePieceOfState,
  getAnotherPieceOfState,
  (somePiece, anotherPiece) => somePiece + anotherPiece
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  someProp: getSomeCombinedState(state)
});
```

Note. it's common to prefix the name of selectors with `get` and to prefix the name of a selector factory (a function that returns a selector) with `makeGet`.

Some times creating a selector factory is necessary though if you wan't to make a selector that is dependant on a property that is not in the state.

You can read more about that here [Accessing React Props in Selectors](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect#accessing-react-props-in-selectors)

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it absolutely right in the second example. This is a standard practice.

There's no need to do wrap `makeSelectError` to another function.